# How would you send a message from a web application to a phone as a text message, and vice versa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sms

I want a web application and a phone to be able to send messages to one another, and for the phone to receive the messages as text messages via SMS. What would be the easiest way to do this? I prefer for any examples to be in Ruby/RoR.

Comment: You need an SMS gateway. Depending on the gateway the code will be different. It could be as simple as sending an email to the gateway, which delivers it as an SMS to the phone number(s) of your choice. I doubt anyone will show you any code in response to this question. Good luck.

Comment: how do you get access to an SMS gateway?

Comment: I have used one called Clickatell, but there are lots. Just google for "SMS gateway".

Answer (score 2):

The most developer friendly way to send SMS is throught http://www.twilio.com/

Answer (score 1):

I used [www.clickatell.com](http://www.clickatell.com) , they have api and a ruby gem for accessing their api. More info about the gem can be found here: http://clickatell.rubyforge.org/

Comment: cool! What about receiving messages via SMS? Could you even use it to see if a user has read your message?

Comment: @user773804 Yes, you can sign up at Clickatell for a two-way messaging gateway on this link: http://www.clickatell.com/products/two_way.php   I'm not sure if exists any option to see if a user has read your message. I think this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy on heroku, you aldo have moonshadow as an add-on. I recommend you to check different sms gateways tho, because the pricing varies A LOT

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://www.bluevia.com

Answer (score 0):

Buy credits from a sms gateway provider.

Add require 'net/http' in your environments file if you are working on rails 3.x (not required for rails 2 apps).

```
def send_welcome_sms
  url=URI.parse("http://webaddress.com");
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)  
  message = "message goes here"
  request.set_form_data({'username'=>"abc", 'password'=>"xyz", 'to'=> "some number", 'text'=> "#{message}", 'from'=> "someone"})
  response = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(request) }
  # If U are Behind The Proxy Comment Above Line And  Uncomment Below Line, Give The Proxy Ip & Port
  #response = Net::HTTP::Proxy("PROXY IP", PROXYPORT).new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(request) }

  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess
    puts response.body
  else
    response.body
    response.error!
  end
end
```